# Growth estimate of $f''(x)$ for smooth $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with smooth inverse and $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question is as in the title.

If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, has a smooth inverse and $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$, can we say anything about the growth bound of $f''(x)$?

I am trying to use the L'Hospital formula, but it does not seem to work well..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Consider smooth functions approximating a "staircase" shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no growth bound.

Let's say $f$ is increasing.
You have $0 < f'(x) < \infty$ with $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)\; dt \le x$ for $x > 0$. The graph of $f'$ could have arbitrarily
tall "bumps" as long as they are narrow enough to not make much of a difference to the integral.  In those bumps, $|f''|$ could be arbitrarily large.  Examples are not hard to construct.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure we can find a bound. See this example: f(x) = xsin(x), f'(x) = sen(x)+xcos(x),f''(x) = 2cos(x) - xsin(x). f'' will grow indefinitely

Comment: But $x\sin(x)$ doesn't have inverse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can't.

Let $g(x)$ be any smooth function s.t. $g(0) = 0$, $|g'(x)| \leq 1$. Then $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{g(x)}{4}$ satisfies your conditions, but it's second derivative is $\frac{g''(x)}{4}$, which can be very large.

For example, consider $g(x) = \int_0^x \sin(x^2)\, dx$. Then we have $g'(x) = \sin(x^2)$ and so $|g'(x)| \leq 1$, but $g''(x) = 2x\cos(x^2)$, so it's not bounded.